# Set/Get user information from a xmpp server: python

Tags: python, xmpp

I am new in python and I am trying to create a testing python script to test different actions on my XMPP server. I already was able to test the login of my user and now I want to get the information that the server is sending (stanza) and set new information.

I have read several webs and I am not very clear with all this information. The main source has been sleekxmpp.com.

I have my stanza:

```
<iq type='get' to= 'chat.net'  id='id1'>
  <aa xmlns='http://myweb.com' />
</iq>

<iq type='result' to= 'chat.net'  id='id1'>
  <aa xmlns='http://myweb.com' >
    <name>My name as included in sent mails<name>
  <lang>en</lang>
    <mail>My mail as included in sent mails</mail>
  </aa>
</iq>
```

I want to get the information and also set one of the parameters (lets say name) but I don't know how.

```
class user_info(sleekxmpp.stanza.Iq):

    self.get_query()
```

I must do it in python. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is create a custom stanza class for your stanza. Here's one that will work for the example you have:

```
from sleekxmpp import Iq
from sleekxmpp.xmlstream import ElementBase, register_stanza_plugin

class AA(ElementBase):
    name = 'aa'
    namespace = 'http://myweb.com'
    plugin_attrib = 'aa'
    interfaces = set(['name', 'lang', 'mail'])
    sub_interfaces = interfaces

register_stanza_plugin(Iq, AA)
```

Ok, so what does all of that do? The `name` field specifies that the XML object's root tag is 'aa', and `namespace` specifies the root tag's namespace; obvious so far I hope.

The `plugin_attrib` field is the name that can be used to access this stanza from the parent stanza. For example, you should already be familiar with how you can use `iq['type']` or `iq['from']` to extract data out of an Iq stanza. With `plugin_attrib` set to `"aa"`, then you can use `iq['aa']` to get a reference to the AA content.

The `interfaces` set is the set of key names that this stanza provides for extracting information, just like working with dictionaries. For example an Iq stanza has 'to', 'from', 'type', etc in its interfaces set. By default, accessing and modifying these keys will create or modify attributes of the stanza's main element. So, at this point, your stanza would behave like this:

```
aa = AA()
aa['name'] = 'foo'
print aa
"<aa xmlns='http://myweb.com' name='foo' />"
```

Now, to instead map interface keys to subelements instead of attributes, they need to be in the `sub_interfaces` set. So by setting `sub_interfaces = interfaces` the above example would now work like so:

```
aa = AA()
aa['name'] = 'foo'
print aa
"<aa xmlns='http://myweb.com'><name>foo</name></aa>"
```

If you needed something more advanced, you could also define methods of the form get_* / set_* / del_* where * is the interface name which will then be used to extract or modify data.

So, all together, you will be able to do:

```
iq = Iq()
# ... set iq parameters
iq.enable('aa')  # Add an initial, empty aa element.
try:
    resp = iq.send()
    print(resp['aa']['name'])
    # ..., etc
except XMPPError:
    print('There was an error')
```

Also, don't forget that we have the sleek@conference.jabber.org chat room for SleekXMPP help if you need it.

Comment: First, tnx Lance for this detailed answer. It really helped me to put ideas together from all the information that I was reading.
I tried something with your info+what I found online and I got this:
    'class OO(ElementBase):
    
        name = 'aa'
        namespace = 'http://myweb.com/' 
        plugin_attrib = 'aa'
        interfaces = set(['name', 'lang', 'mail'])
        sub_interfaces = interfaces
    
        def getMail(self):
           present = self.xml.find('{%s}mail' %self.namespace)
           return present '

It does nothing

Comment: I was wondering if I have to somehow “call “ the AA class at my __main__. If so, how to… Because then I tried this:
     aa = AA()
     iq.enable(‘aa’)
     try:
       resp = iq.send()
       print(resp[‘aa’][‘name]
     except XMPPError:
       print(‘There is an error’)
And nothing happens as well.
Thanks again!
Regards,

Comment: First, don't forget the register_stanza_plugin(Iq, AA) call. The final example from above would be meant to run in the event handler for the session_start event, after sending initial presence and requesting the roster. The echo_client.py example serves as a good starting point for that. There is just one small correction that needs to be made. Instead of iq = Iq(), it would need to be iq = self.Iq(), where self is the ClientXMPP instance.

Comment: Thanks Lance, with your answer and some links with scripts (written by you hehe) I have managed to perform the Get/Set! Now I am working on writing the specific methods to have a more organized script for my test. Thanks again!